# What is optim doing here?

Tags: r, statistics

I am using Gaussian Process regression and wish to maximize the likelihood by optimizing the parameters phi and sigma_squared. So, I start with some data, I calculate a distance matrix, the absolute differences between each data point, and then create a function that defines the covariance matrix (which includes the two parameters to be optimized) and the log-likelihood function. The code is below. I'm getting very strange results, such that the loglikelihood is very small. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

```
dist_mat<-matrix(,nrow=length(x),ncol=length(x))
for(i in 1:nrow(dist_mat)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(dist_mat)){
    dist_mat[i,j]<-abs(x[i]-x[j])
  }
}
covmat<-matrix(,nrow=nrow(dist_mat),ncol=ncol(dist_mat))
loglike<-function(x,par){
  for(i in 1:nrow(dist_mat)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(dist_mat)){
      covmat[i,j]<-par[1]*exp(-(dist_mat[i,j])/(2*par[2]^2))
    }
  }
  llike<- 1*(-0.5*t(x)%*%solve(covmat,x)-0.5*determinant((2*pi*covmat),log=TRUE)$modulus[1])
  return(llike)
}
optim(c(0.00001,1),fn=loglike,x=x)
```

Comment: I thought minimize was what `optim` was supposed to be doing. At least that’s how I read the docs: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optim

Comment: Oh wow, I feel silly. Thank you!

Comment: To transform a maximizing problem into a minimizing problem, multiply your objective function with minus one.